# Django crispy forms - VariableDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to do the tutorial at http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html

When i try to open the page i get the following error;

```
VariableDoesNotExist at / Failed lookup for key [example_form] in u
```

It tries to look up example_form but can not find it. As i am really new to django and python i am at a loss where the missing part is. Also do i need a views.py in this situation or can i directly reference the forms from the urls.py?

My urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',

        url(r'^$', 'ian.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

My views.py

```
def home(request):  
    return render_to_response("index.html",
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    like_website = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label = "Do you like this website?",
        choices = ((1, "Yes"), (0, "No")),
        coerce = lambda x: bool(int(x)),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        initial = '1',
        required = True,
    )

    favorite_food = forms.CharField(
        label = "What is your favorite food?",
        max_length = 80,
        required = True,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit_survey'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

My index.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy example_form example_form.helper %}
```

Comment: That documentation isn't intended as a step-by-step tutorial - it's just documenting how to use `crispy-forms` with `Django`. Work through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) first to get familiar with how different parts of the framework interact with each other before trying to integrate a third-party app like `crispy-forms`. After that tutorial you may also want to look at [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) and its associated [Django template](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) for best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass a form instance to the view's renderer.

Very simply to at least see your form rendered...

```
def home(request):  
    example_form = ExampleForm()
    return render_to_response("index.html",
                              {"example_form": example_form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You will want to look at the django docs to see how to handle data returned from the form and such, but that will let you see it rendered on the page.